# How to read an argument value from xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the code in an .xml file, I would like to assign to the field the value of the attribute from the .xml file.

**.csharp**

```
private static string camera_model_c1_set = xml_read_set_cip_c1.Descendants("root").ElementAt("camera_model_c1_set").Att
```

**.csharp**

```
Parameter name: value '
XDocument name_of_file_xml = new XDocument(
            new XComment("document"),
            new XElement("root",
                new XElement("name", new XAttribute ("name2", myvalue ))
                )
            );
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--document-->
<root>
  <name name2="myvalue" />
</root>
```

and I want to get this "myvalue" to .cs code to:

```
static string new_my_var = ... (?)
```

I have

```
 XDocument xml_doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

I care about using `XDocument` in this code. (instead of `XmlDocument`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Actually I dont have results." - what exactly do you mean by that? What does your current code return? I wouldn't expect it to compile, to be honest... it would help if you could provide a clear [mcve]. Currently you've got code to *create* an `XDocument`, but presumably you don't need that if you've already got the file... but we need your *actual* code to read the document, along with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for reading the attribute from an xml file :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Path/document.xml");
XmlNodeList elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name");     
static string new_my_var = elem.Attributes["name2"].Value;
```

Comment: I have:

XDocument xml_doc = XDocument.Load(path); |||||

I care about using XDocument in this code. (instead of XmlDocument)

Comment: You can use something like this:                                                                   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path)                                                           xdoc.Root.Element("name").Attribute("name2").Value;

Comment: CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'program.xdoc'

Comment: like this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d89607f3-3030-45ef-a83e-9abf3e9dece7/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Was the above solution helpful for your problem?